# "size" attribute give a different result on Linux

Tags: html, css, linux, windows

I tried for the first time to visit the website I'm working on from Linux, and every  fields with a size attribute are longer.

[The normal size, on Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atBqk.png)

[The size on Ubuntu 16.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdP89.png)

```
<input type="text" size="66" value=""/>
<textarea cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="text" size="66" value=""/>
<input type="text" size="66" value=""/>
```

I really think it is due to the OS, and not to the browser, the website has been tested a lot on Windows.

I also heard that Linux displays fonts differently than Windows, but I didn't find anything related to the size attribute.

This is happening everywhere on the website, and I need to find another solution that just replacing the size with some css style..

Comment: Can you please add some code? It might help to set some class with width attribute to the input fields. like; width: 100%;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross browser setting input "size"-attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313704/cross-browser-setting-input-size-attribute)

Comment: I really need a solution keeping the size attribute. The different answers in the other post all suggest to use css width:, but I can't.

Comment: Well, that is not going to happen. The way to make some HTML element a certain width is to assign a `width` property to it. That is the solution. If you don't want to do that, well, sorry.

Comment: By the way, I'm trying your code in various browsers, and they're all different. On average, the inputs are about 30% wider than the textarea, also in Windows. So there is no "normal" size.

Answer (score 0):

In fact there isn't other solution than replacing the size by the width property.

I changed it everywhere on the website and everything work perfectly fine now!